# Joomla! 3.4 Menus not appearing

Tags: joomla, joomla3.4

New Joomla! user here, for some reason when I set the menu assignment for a menu module to be seen on all pages, I can see it on every page of my site, but when I try change the assignment to where the menu only shows up on certain pages it disappears completely. This is rather confusing as no matter which pages I check on the assignment page the menu isn't displayed unless all of the boxes are checked.

EDIT:

This seems to be the case after a login redirect, How would I tell joomla to display a menu after a user logs in? to give more context the menu is displayed on: http://localhost/sitename/index.php/welcome but not on the redirect page: http://localhost/sitename/index.php?id=3

I think the discrepancy in the urls is what is throwing joomla off

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by updating (issue with SEF enabled in 3.4.x):

libraries/cms/application/site.php

```
if ($router->getMode() == JROUTER_MODE_SEF){
    //$document->setBase(htmlspecialchars(JUri::current()));
}
```

This is clearing out the query string, after upgrade you'll need if not fixed to do this again.

I've found this issue in 3.4 upto 3.4.4 today.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by using the redirect manager, I just redirected the strange urls to my desired pages that display my desired menus.